# MySQL Select Union; Filter by Shared Relation?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7, union

Currently, I have 3 tables *(see structure below)*, `speakers`, `venues`, and `events`. I'm trying to do a relevance search on the names of the `speakers` and `venues`. However, on the Search Results page, if the `speaker` and `venue` share the same next upcoming event, I'll be showing it on the page along with their opposite (Speaker|Venue) model.

As a result, I end up with duplicate items on my search page. For instance, if they search for 'Adam Wathan', they might see something like:

```
+------------------------------+  
| **Adam Wathan**              |    
|  Wathan Theatre             |  
|  Jan. 9th @ 5:15 PM        |  
+------------------------------+  
+------------------------------+  
| **Wathan Theatre**           | <- Same as above, but opposite primary model.   
|  Adam Wathan               |  
|  Jan. 9th @ 5:15 PM        |  
+------------------------------+  
+------------------------------+  
| **Mike Wathan**              | <- Match should be displayed even with no upcoming events.   
|  See past events.          |  
+------------------------------+
```

> **Note** I am intentionally including matches that don't have upcoming events too.
>
> **Note** This query is  just giving me a list of models to fetch in subsequent queries. It is not responsible for obtaining all of the information displayed in the illustration above.

In the instance where both the matching `speaker` and the `venue` share the same next upcoming `event`, it should only return the most relevant of the two (or default to `speaker` if equal).

> Yes, I could filter them in the application logic, but that would mess up the pagination as there wouldn't be the expected X entries on the page and the total count would be incorrect if it counts the related duplicates.

Finally, I'd also like for it to return the ID of the next upcoming event (`upcoming_event`) if one exists, but I keep running into this ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY error; which I understand the purpose of and would like to keep it enabled, but I'm not used to working around it yet.

Databases are not my strong suit and I've spent 4 days getting this as far as I have. It works well enough and I wouldn't be horribly upset if I can't add these improvements... but I would love to get this working how I had imagined it. Unfortunately, despite hours of research and reading, I'm afraid I've accomplished all I can do without help on this specific issue. I'm also open to alternative methods if it renders the same results, especially if it'll be more performant.

PS: Sorry about the title, really not sure how to describe this question simply. Please edit if you can form a better title after reading the question.

### Online Example

> [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/snkGVyhvKCRwBFDeRhMpZP/0)

### Database Structure

```
# Data structure
CREATE TABLE `speakers`  (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

CREATE TABLE `venues`  (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

CREATE TABLE `events`  (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `venue_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `speaker_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `starts_at` timestamp(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0),
  `ends_at` timestamp(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

# Sample Data
INSERT INTO `speakers` VALUES (1, 'Evan You', '2019-01-04 13:12:16', '2019-01-04 13:12:16');
INSERT INTO `speakers` VALUES (2, 'Freek Van Der Herten', '2019-01-04 13:12:16', '2019-01-04 13:12:16');
INSERT INTO `speakers` VALUES (3, 'Matt Stauffer', '2019-01-04 13:12:16', '2019-01-04 13:12:16');
INSERT INTO `speakers` VALUES (4, 'Adam Wathan', '2019-01-04 13:12:16', '2019-01-04 13:12:16');
INSERT INTO `speakers` VALUES (5, 'Wes Bos', '2019-01-04 13:12:16', '2019-01-04 13:12:16');
INSERT INTO `speakers` VALUES (6, 'Taylor Otwell', '2019-01-04 13:12:16', '2019-01-04 13:12:16');
INSERT INTO `speakers` VALUES (7, 'Steve Schoger', '2019-01-04 13:12:16', '2019-01-04 13:12:16');
INSERT INTO `speakers` VALUES (8, 'Rizqi Djamaluddin', '2019-01-04 13:12:16', '2019-01-04 13:12:16');
INSERT INTO `speakers` VALUES (9, 'Katerina Trajchevska', '2019-01-04 13:12:16', '2019-01-04 13:12:16');
INSERT INTO `speakers` VALUES (10, 'Adam Culp', '2019-01-04 13:12:16', '2019-01-04 13:12:16');

INSERT INTO `venues` VALUES (1, 'Otwell Plaza', '2019-01-04 13:12:16', '2019-01-04 13:12:16');
INSERT INTO `venues` VALUES (2, 'Laravel Park', '2019-01-04 13:12:16', '2019-01-04 13:12:16');
INSERT INTO `venues` VALUES (3, 'Wathan Theatre', '2019-01-04 13:12:16', '2019-01-04 13:12:16');
INSERT INTO `venues` VALUES (4, 'Way University', '2019-01-04 13:12:16', '2019-01-04 13:12:16');
INSERT INTO `venues` VALUES (5, 'Fidao Group', '2019-01-04 13:12:16', '2019-01-04 13:12:16');

INSERT INTO `events` VALUES (1, 1, 2, '2019-02-25 12:15:00', '2019-02-25 18:00:00', '2019-01-04 13:12:22', '2019-01-04 13:12:22');
INSERT INTO `events` VALUES (2, 4, 3, '2019-01-09 05:15:00', NULL, '2019-01-04 13:12:22', '2019-01-04 13:12:22');
INSERT INTO `events` VALUES (3, 4, 5, '2018-01-09 05:15:00', NULL, '2019-01-04 13:12:22', '2019-01-04 13:12:22');
INSERT INTO `events` VALUES (4, 4, 5, '2019-02-09 05:15:00', NULL, '2019-01-04 13:12:22', '2019-01-04 13:12:22');
```

### Database Query

```
(
    SELECT
        `venues`.`id`,
        `venues`.`name`,
        'venues' AS type,
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "adam wathan Stau" THEN 500 ELSE 0 END ) +

        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "adam" THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "adam%" THEN 80 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%adam" THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%adam%" THEN 40 ELSE 0 END ) +

        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "wathan" THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "wathan%" THEN 80 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%wathan" THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%wathan%" THEN 40 ELSE 0 END ) +

        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "Stau" THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "Stau%" THEN 80 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%Stau" THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%Stau%" THEN 40 ELSE 0 END ) +

        ( CASE WHEN min( `events`.`starts_at` >= '2019-01-5 12:00:00' ) THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) AS `relevance` 
    FROM `venues`
        LEFT JOIN `events` ON `events`.`venue_id` = `venues`.`id` 
    GROUP BY `venues`.`id` 
    HAVING `relevance` > 50 
) UNION (
    SELECT
        `speakers`.`id`,
        `speakers`.`name`,
        'speakers' AS type,
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "adam wathan Stau" THEN 500 ELSE 0 END ) +

        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "adam" THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "adam%" THEN 80 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%adam" THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%adam%" THEN 40 ELSE 0 END ) +

        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "wathan" THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "wathan%" THEN 80 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%wathan" THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%wathan%" THEN 40 ELSE 0 END ) +

        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "Stau" THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "Stau%" THEN 80 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%Stau" THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%Stau%" THEN 40 ELSE 0 END ) +

        ( CASE WHEN min( `events`.`starts_at` >= '2019-01-5 12:00:00' ) THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) AS `relevance` 
    FROM `speakers`
        LEFT JOIN `events` ON `events`.`speaker_id` = `speakers`.`id` 
    GROUP BY `speakers`.`id` 
    HAVING `relevance` > 50 
) 
ORDER BY
    `relevance` DESC,
    `name` DESC 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL 5.7 - as tagged…:

Still telling from

> Results 1 (4, Adam Wathan, speakers) and 2 (3, Wathan Theatre, venues) are both from the Event with an ID of 2

the `INSERT` for event #2 should probably read

`` INSERT INTO `events` VALUES (2, 3, 4, '2019-01-09 05:15:00', NULL, '2019-01-04 13:12:22', '2019-01-04 13:12:22'); ``

From here, let's compose the final result step by step - using a sequence of views and a final select:

---

```
CREATE VIEW `DataCollector` AS SELECT * FROM (
   (
    SELECT
        `venues`.`id`,
        `events`.`id` AS `event_id`,
        `venues`.`name`,
        'venues' AS type,
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "adam wathan Stau" THEN 500 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "adam" THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "adam%" THEN 80 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%adam" THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%adam%" THEN 40 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "wathan" THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "wathan%" THEN 80 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%wathan" THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%wathan%" THEN 40 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "Stau" THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "Stau%" THEN 80 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%Stau" THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%Stau%" THEN 40 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN min( `events`.`starts_at` >= '2019-01-5 12:00:00' ) THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) AS `relevance` 
    FROM `venues`
        LEFT JOIN `events` ON `events`.`venue_id` = `venues`.`id` 
    GROUP BY `venues`.`id`, `events`.`id` 
    HAVING `relevance` > 50 
   )
   UNION ALL
   (
    SELECT
        `speakers`.`id`,
        `events`.`id` AS `event_id`,
        `speakers`.`name`,
        'speakers' AS type,
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "adam wathan Stau" THEN 500 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "adam" THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "adam%" THEN 80 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%adam" THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%adam%" THEN 40 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "wathan" THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "wathan%" THEN 80 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%wathan" THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%wathan%" THEN 40 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "Stau" THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "Stau%" THEN 80 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%Stau" THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%Stau%" THEN 40 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN min( `events`.`starts_at` >= '2019-01-5 12:00:00' ) THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) AS `relevance` 
    FROM `speakers`
        LEFT JOIN `events` ON `events`.`speaker_id` = `speakers`.`id` 
    GROUP BY `speakers`.`id`, `events`.`id` 
    HAVING `relevance` > 50 
   )
) `_DataCollector`;

CREATE VIEW `DuplicateFilter` AS (
  SELECT
    `event_id`
    , MAX(`relevance`) AS `max_relevance`
    , MIN(`relevance`) AS `min_relevance`
  FROM `DataCollector`
  WHERE `event_id` IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY `event_id`
);

SELECT
  `DataCollector`.`id`
  , `DataCollector`.`event_id`
  , `DataCollector`.`name`
  , `DataCollector`.`type`
  , `DataCollector`.`relevance`
FROM `DataCollector`
JOIN `DuplicateFilter`
  ON `DataCollector`.`event_id` = `DuplicateFilter`.`event_id`
  AND `DataCollector`.`relevance` = `DuplicateFilter`.`max_relevance`
  AND `DataCollector`.`relevance` = `DuplicateFilter`.`min_relevance`
  AND `DataCollector`.`type` = 'speakers'
UNION ALL
(SELECT
  `DataCollector`.`id`
  , `DataCollector`.`event_id`
  , `DataCollector`.`name`
  , `DataCollector`.`type`
  , `DataCollector`.`relevance`
FROM `DataCollector`
JOIN `DuplicateFilter`
  ON `DataCollector`.`event_id` = `DuplicateFilter`.`event_id`
  AND `DataCollector`.`relevance` = `DuplicateFilter`.`max_relevance`
  AND `DataCollector`.`relevance` > `DuplicateFilter`.`min_relevance`
)
UNION ALL
(SELECT
  `id`
  , `event_id`
  , `name`
  , `type`
  , `relevance`
FROM `DataCollector`
WHERE `event_id` IS NULL)
ORDER BY `relevance` DESC, `name` DESC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
;
```

**N.B.**

- As performance was mentioned, all `UNION` have been turned into `UNION ALL`. This should help - but does not consistently do so in DB Fiddle…
- Much more is probably to be gained in that respect by streamlining the **relevance** calculation - if at all feasible.

See it in action: [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mKznPSS9mxCS3MC9SwVzu1/1). (With a second `SELECT` to check the impact of `UNION ALL` right away…)

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: So, with this approach I'd need to first run a query to create the view with the search terms... then query the view... then delete the view? 

How do companies create such flexible relevance searches that are so fast? I can imagine this will only get slower as tables grow. Have any links or suggested reading materials for how I'd go about improving the search's flexibility and speed beyond what has been covered here? Are other databases used? Third-party reverse indexes? Something else?

Comment: @user1960364 Seen from this perspective: This approach should work fine for infrequent data analysis type work (done once every so often) - much less if at all for frequent ad hoc queries. Whether or not this is feasible in your context depends on the actual frequencies of such queries. (The **DataCollector** could be left untouched until the next `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DataCollector`.) Alternatively, the view names could include something like a session ID with the whole set of views being created on the fly, and dropped after the final select.

Comment: It's basically meetup type app where this search will return upcoming events. That said, the query will be done frequently (anytime someone on the site searches). Hence why I feel like there should be a better way... I'm just clueless as to where to look. This is definitely a good start as I have learned a lot from your solutions. Unfortunately, I think in the long run, I will need something more performant but don't know what to consider as a possible long-terms goal/solution.

Comment: @user1960364 On the more general account: Various things come to mind: Other databases or even the most recent MySQL version ;-), stuff like Lucene indexes, denormalizing the data model, cutting back on the flexibility,… Still: How frequent is "frequently" righ now? Could the MySQL 5.7 version work until you switch to MySQL 8?

Comment: The site is still in development, so it has 0 popularity at the moment and I may launch with MySQL 8... I need to do more research on it first. Either way, I'm sure these will suffice just fine... I'm just genuinely curious as to how I'd go that extra step forward for if/when I need something better. For instance, services like Algolia seem to be pretty flexible, but I don't want to build a site that relies on so many 3rd party services that it's too costly to operate. The free tiers often just get you locked in and make it difficult to change.

Comment: @user1960364 OK - at first sight, one might wonder, whether mixing speaker and venue names does really make a lot of sense. But as soon as you replace venue by, e.g., session title…

Comment: One road to check: Maintain a table, which lists all currently known speakers, events, etc. - with all to be searched details combined into one long text field, then a discriminator field (to record the source table), and the ID in the originating table. Use that know-it-all table for the maximum flexibility search, and combine the result with the details from the individual fact tables. If IDs are unique across all fact tables in total, you could join the search result to the `UNION` of the fact tables. - Not sure, though, how well that would perform for lots of data in MySQL…

Comment: Makes sense... even if not the most scalable solution, it sounds like it'd scale better than what's currently in place. At the very least, it's a good interim solution to buy time if something more needs done in the future. I don't plan to implement it right away, I just don't like not thinking ahead and knowing what my next step will be when the time comes... Thanks again for taking the time to answer and continuing the conversation in the comments. It's been very educational. :)

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL 8 as used in the DB Fiddle provided:

Telling from

> Results 1 (4, Adam Wathan, speakers) and 2 (3, Wathan Theatre, venues) are both from the Event with an ID of 2

your `INSERT` for event #2 should probably read

`` INSERT INTO `events` VALUES (2, 3, 4, '2019-01-09 05:15:00', NULL, '2019-01-04 13:12:22', '2019-01-04 13:12:22'); ``

From here, let's compose the final result step by step - using CTE:

- Add **`events`.`id`** to both `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` for later evaluation.
- Find the maximum (and minimum) relevance for each event for later filtering.
- Assemble the final result.

---

```
WITH
`T1` AS (
(
    SELECT
        `venues`.`id`,
        `events`.`id` AS `event_id`,
        `venues`.`name`,
        'venues' AS type,
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "adam wathan Stau" THEN 500 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "adam" THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "adam%" THEN 80 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%adam" THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%adam%" THEN 40 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "wathan" THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "wathan%" THEN 80 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%wathan" THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%wathan%" THEN 40 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "Stau" THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "Stau%" THEN 80 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%Stau" THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%Stau%" THEN 40 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN min( `events`.`starts_at` >= '2019-01-5 12:00:00' ) THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) AS `relevance` 
    FROM `venues`
        LEFT JOIN `events` ON `events`.`venue_id` = `venues`.`id` 
    GROUP BY `venues`.`id`, `events`.`id` 
    HAVING `relevance` > 50 
) UNION (
    SELECT
        `speakers`.`id`,
        `events`.`id` AS `event_id`,
        `speakers`.`name`,
        'speakers' AS type,
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "adam wathan Stau" THEN 500 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "adam" THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "adam%" THEN 80 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%adam" THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%adam%" THEN 40 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "wathan" THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "wathan%" THEN 80 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%wathan" THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%wathan%" THEN 40 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "Stau" THEN 100 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "Stau%" THEN 80 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%Stau" THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN `name` LIKE "%Stau%" THEN 40 ELSE 0 END ) +
        ( CASE WHEN min( `events`.`starts_at` >= '2019-01-5 12:00:00' ) THEN 50 ELSE 0 END ) AS `relevance` 
    FROM `speakers`
        LEFT JOIN `events` ON `events`.`speaker_id` = `speakers`.`id` 
    GROUP BY `speakers`.`id`, `events`.`id` 
    HAVING `relevance` > 50 
) 
),
`DuplicateFilter` AS (
  SELECT
    `event_id`
    , MAX(`relevance`) AS `max_relevance`
    , MIN(`relevance`) AS `min_relevance`
  FROM `T1`
  WHERE `event_id` IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY `event_id`
),
`Final` AS (
  (SELECT
    `T1`.`id`
    , `T1`.`event_id`
    , `T1`.`name`
    , `T1`.`type`
    , `T1`.`relevance`
  FROM `T1`
  JOIN `DuplicateFilter`
    ON `T1`.`event_id` = `DuplicateFilter`.`event_id`
    AND `T1`.`relevance` = `DuplicateFilter`.`max_relevance`
    AND `T1`.`relevance` = `DuplicateFilter`.`min_relevance`
    AND `T1`.`type` = 'speakers'
  )
  UNION
  (SELECT
    `T1`.`id`
    , `T1`.`event_id`
    , `T1`.`name`
    , `T1`.`type`
    , `T1`.`relevance`
  FROM `T1`
  JOIN `DuplicateFilter`
    ON `T1`.`event_id` = `DuplicateFilter`.`event_id`
    AND `T1`.`relevance` = `DuplicateFilter`.`max_relevance`
    AND `T1`.`relevance` > `DuplicateFilter`.`min_relevance`
  )
  UNION
  (SELECT
    `id`
    , `event_id`
    , `name`
    , `type`
    , `relevance`
  FROM `T1`
  WHERE `event_id` IS NULL)
)
SELECT
  * FROM `Final` ORDER BY `relevance` DESC, `name` DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
;
```

**N.B.**

- The order of `UNION`ed statements should not be relevant - but appears to be in **Final**. If the third part (checking for **event_id** being **NULL**) goes first, the output of the other two statements is not returned.
- An effort has been made to accomodate your requirements around shared upcoming events - but has not been fully verified for lack of data.

See it in action: [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mKznPSS9mxCS3MC9SwVzu1/0).

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: Wow, that is intimidating to look at! It appears to accomplish the goal, but I'll have to take some time to play with and fully understand it to be sure. I did notice that it nearly doubled my query time though, are there any ways to optimize it?

Comment: Also, would it be hard to adapt it to MySQL 5.7? I tagged the question with 5.7 but didn't realize I had DB Fiddle on MySQL 8. Not quite ready to make the jump to 8 yet. Sorry for the confusion. 

Comment: Are you free to create a view or two in the database?

Comment: I've never worked with views in a database, but I'm sure I could if necessary. I've always been under the impression that it's usually best to avoid them... or that I should do things differently if I'm needing them.

Comment: @user1960364 Despite https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-syntax.html saying "A view can be created from many kinds of SELECT statements. It can refer to base tables or other views. It can use joins, UNION, and subqueries." it seems to me, 5.7 does NOT allow UNION in views - at least not in the installations available to me. Compare https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sXd5K6CSdgPaANQXZ9FqAD/0 vs. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sXd5K6CSdgPaANQXZ9FqAD/1 Would you, please, check the DB Fiddle snippets in your own installation?

Comment: Neither of those work, but I did some research and found this which does work... I don't understand why it does but yours doesn't. Perhaps you can make some sense of it? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sXd5K6CSdgPaANQXZ9FqAD/2

Comment: @user1960364 Good hint. Thanks! So how about: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qxx74a1PkYxmRyDh2yfMSs/2

Comment: Yes, that one works...